# Testing Bits in VBA

Tags: vba

Is it OK to test bits in VBA in the manner shown below, or does it have some hidden gotchas ?

```
Dim x As Byte
x = FooFn(42)

If (x And &H80) Then Debug.Print "The MSB is set"
```

or must I test it like this:

```
Dim x As Byte
x = FooFn(42)

If (x And &H80) <> 0 Then Debug.Print "The MSB is set"
```

On the other hand, what is the optimal way to test whether this bit is **clear** (not set) ?
Is this the best I can do:

```
Dim x As Byte
x = FooFn(43)

If (x And &H80) = 0 Then Debug.Print "The MSB is not set"
```

Also, what is this the minimum amount of parentheses I can get away with ?

Comment: The only "gotcha" I can think if is when you are *not* using a straight Power of 2, for example `x AND &H2A`, where 42, 32, 2 and 8 would all return non-zero value (But, sometimes that's what you want, e.g. using `x AND &HFF00` to isolate the Green component of an RGB Colour)

Comment: q2 is limited by 8192: http://diylightanimation.com/index.php?topic=7992.0#:~:text=Maximum%20Number%20of%20Characters%20in%20an%20Excel%20%282010%29,be%20in%20an%20Excel%20%282010%29%20formula%20are%208%2C192.